# How can I hide the dock and menubar in my fullscreen game?

Tags: macos, cocoa, 2d-games, xojo

I'm writing a game that will run in a fullscreen window. I'm using Xojo to code it (therefore any boolean window properties that might be availble in Xcode / Interface Builder are not an option).

Is there a plist key/value I can set in my app that will hide the application menubar and the dock when my window is set to full screen?

Needs to work on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Get the [macoslib](https://github.com/macoslib/macoslib)

It contains extensions for NSWindow that can do this. Just search the project for "fullscreen".

There is also a demo. If you run the project, open the menu bar: *Examples* -> *Cocoa* -> *NSWindow*. That window has a "Toggle Fullscreen" button for testing.

Comment: Thanks Thom, whilst this works, it shows a one second animation of the window moving to fullscreen. Since this is a game, I need a way to just launch the window at full screen rather than stretch to fullscreen - it just looks weird. Thoughts?

Comment: I know there are some older APIs for this purpose, maybe they do this better, but I do not have them handy right now. Also, the macoslib function works on a window, and you need the app-wide setting instead, it appears. Have you checked if the MBS plugins offer a function for that, in case you are not comfortable writing your own declares?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to place in the window Open event :

```
  self.LiveResize = False
  self.MenuBarVisible = false
  self.FullScreen = true
```

First line turns off animation,

Second line turns off UI elements (dock and menu bar),

Third line makes the window full screen